# Why is the Lie derivative of two vector fields $L_X Y$ equal to the Lie bracket $[X, y]$?

Tags: geometry

it is me again. I can understand the Lie derivative of forms and maps: it makes sense expanding the terms as $L_X \omega = \iota_a(d\omega) + d(\iota_a \omega)$, or even $L_X f = df(X) = f_{;i}X^i$. But I am not following how can the operation $L_X$ of a vector field $Y$ is the Lie algebra $[X, Y]$.

Let us not assume some base structure, like (pseudo-)Riemmanian manifold, but just a smooth manifold, shall we? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Back up. $L_X\omega$ is certainly not $\iota_Xd\omega$. Have you looked at any standard texts in differentiable manifolds? $K_XY=[X,Y]$ is a standard result in every such book, and it’s been discussed in lots of posts here, too. Metric structures are totally irrelevant.

Comment: I see, thanks. I also fixed the Lie derivative of a $n$-form as Cartan's formula. There must be a reason why it is called "magic formula"... :/ Regardless, I am honored to receive an answer of a veteran, there must be something on my question that woke your attention. :)

Comment: You can see some discussion in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524410/computing-lie-derivative/1524543#1524543). Where exactly are you stuck? it's hard to know what exact part of the proof are you asking about.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz As you can see, they define with some confusing notation the Lie derivative as limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathrm d\Phi_X^{-t}Y_{\Phi^t_X(p)}-Y_p}{t}$, which is correct from my point of view. Anytime I cannot understand a concept, I just freeze. I must trust more on people and books, ain't I?